# Why when i try to pass my int pid to my OrderDao class and problem occur?

Tags: java, jpa, model-view-controller

Currently working on my OrderDao which contain insertOrder function
and my Order domain have

`private Products pId`

`public void setPId（Products pId) { this.pId = pId }`

so when i try to set a pid in my OrderDao

```
public Orders insertOrder(int pid) { 
    Orders order = new Orders();
    try {
       manager.getTransaction().begin();

       order.setPId(pid);

       manager.persist(order);
       manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return order;
}
```

it occur problem : int cannot be conveted to Products

its my first try on Java so is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you mean `order.setPId(new Products(pid));`? Anyway, what's confusing about the error message? You are passing an `int` to a method that's expecting a Products object. Side note: class names should not be plurals: name your classes `Order` and `Product` not `Orders` and `Products`.

Comment: yea... i was no idea on that... so maybe I just past Products product into my insertOrder? to become insertOrder(Products product) will it be easy on that?

Comment: for that name is not create myself... is because im working on the JAVA JPA and when i create the entity class it will do for me all the domain classes

Comment: wow new Products(pid) just solve my problem ! Thanks for that!

Comment: It's a big anti pattern to name tables in the plural - the entity being named is the *row*, not the list of rows. Consider a create table statement - it describes the row. Really, the syntax should be `create row ...` not create table IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a constructor for Products that accepts its id:

```
order.setPId(new Products(pid));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setPId（Products pId) { this.pId = pId }
```

You got it wrong here, the setter is expecting a Product object but you passed an Integer instead

Comment: Close, but not correct. OP is passing an `int`, not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the `public void setPId（Products pId)` method of "Orders" class gets a "Products" object as an argument. But you are passing an "int" number.
Replacing `public void setPId（Products pId)` with `public void setPId（int pId)` should fix the problem.

By the way, it's usually a good practice to use singular names for class names like Order and Product.

Answer (score 0):

As we know it's an ORM framework which implicitly understand in terms of object onlys except if you are using native query to insert productId in table. So, whenever we have entity to entity relationship we store it using object reference only.

and in this case method should be:

```
 public void setProduct(Product product){ }
```

inside order class considering OneToOne mapping already done.